# source not found even after editing the source lookup path

Tags: eclipse, debugging

source not foud , i have tried this :

1/edit source lookup path
2/click on the add button 
3/choose java project 
4/choose my project 
when i click on "ok" it takes me back to "source not found"

any help please

Answer (score 0):

Set the source projects before debugging, from the "Debug as..." window, at "sources" tab.

Comment: it didn't work :( , i'm ,using embedded maven and red hat JBoss so i have set the source project from run as... ,started the server in the debug mode and run the maven build (in which i have set the source project )

Comment: I encourage you to post your own verified solution, in order to be archived for future queries.